# Cocurrent frontend and backend sessions in Symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, config, frontend, factories

Is it possible to create two different sessions for frontend interface and backend interface in Symfony2.

Currently if I logout from backend it destroys my frontend and backend sessions all together.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with two different firewall entries each of them having an different security provider.